# Windows 8.1 app Strange behaviour rotating the device

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps, uwp, winrt-xaml

I have notice a strange behaviour executing a simple test for my app. 
The app is running on a tablet device.

1. In portait mode, before rotation,  i have the correct font size.
2. I rotate the device in landscape mode and the app is stretched correctly
3. I rotate again the app in portrait mode but the font size is
   decreased.

Somebody know why this happen?
How can I avoid this behaviour. 
I'm going crazy for 3 days without found a solution

**EDIT**

Testing the app with another device (8' display), the problem is still present.
The problem is present too testing the app with visual studio simulator !!
I don't think is a code problem because my app has 4 pages with 4 different 
ListViews and the problem is present in all pages.

I notice that the font size change when the device is rotate for the first time from portait to landscape. 
The destination FontSize in landscape mode could be accettable, but when in portrait mode i need (is a customer requirement) to go back with the original Font Size

Comment: Try creating another app with different content and if the issue is even there, there must be problem with your device... You could try it on another user account. That may be just some weird bug in windows.

Comment: Or even better would be if you share with us a sample code so we can recreate and try to fix the issue.